# Fill UIView using a percentage

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UIView and percentage number that comes from an API. I need to have the UIView fill with some color based on the percentage.

[Here's the UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy7MK.png)

I've got the basics from another question here.

```
class BadgeView: UIView {
    private let fillView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    private var coeff:CGFloat = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            // Make sure the fillView frame is updated everytime the coeff changes
            updateFillViewFrame()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        // Setup the layer
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height/2.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        // Setup filledView backgroundColor and add it as a subview
        fillView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 220.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
        addSubview(fillView)

        // Update fillView frame in case coeff already has a value
        updateFillViewFrame()
    }

    private func updateFillViewFrame() {
        fillView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height*(1-coeff), width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height*coeff)
    }

    // Setter function to set the coeff animated. If setting it not animated isn't necessary at all, consider removing this func and animate updateFillViewFrame() in coeff didSet
    public func setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations:{ () -> Void in
                self.coeff = coeff
            })
        } else {
            self.coeff = coeff
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function that returns the percentage:

```
    func cargaOKCheckStatus(resultado: NSDictionary) {
        let JSON = resultado

        if let ElapsedPercentual:Int = JSON.value(forKeyPath: "ResponseEntity.ElapsedPercentual") as? Int {
            porcentaje = ElapsedPercentual
            print(porcentaje)
        }
    }
```

The API returns 0%, 10%, 20%, 30% and so on. So if it's 10%, the UIView should be filled a 10% with the light gray. Right now, it is always half filled.

Comment: You can use `setNeedsLayout()` or `setNeedsDisplay()` to force the view to refresh the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- You can use autolayout to simplify things
- Override both `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)` when creating custom views and call the setup in both methods

```
class BadgeView: UIView {

    private let fillView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    private var fillHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private(set) var coeff: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            updateFillViewFrame()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        fillView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 220.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
        fillView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // ensure autolayout works
        addSubview(fillView)

        // pin view to leading, trailing and bottom to the container view
        fillView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        fillView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        fillView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // save the constraint to be changed later
        fillHeightConstraint = fillView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        fillHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        updateFillViewFrame()
    }

    private func updateFillViewFrame() {
        fillHeightConstraint.constant = bounds.height * coeff // change the constraint value
        layoutIfNeeded() // update the layout when a constraint changes
    }

    public func setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations:{ () -> Void in
                self.coeff = coeff
            })
        } else {
            self.coeff = coeff
        }
    }

}
```

This should work, assuming that `coeff` is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But it's not doing anything, how do I pass in the percentage?

Comment: what does your `print(porcentaje)` print?

Comment: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

Comment: so like `badge.setCoeff(coeff: porcentaje / 100, animated: true)`, assuming you declared a `BadgeView` instance called `badge` in your view controller

Comment: Where do I put that? Because I put it in the API if and the viewDidLoad of the ViewController and it's not working

Comment: Sorry but I think you have a problem on the code structure, you should put what you do in the view controller too.

Comment: So what should I do? I think that line should go in the function that returns the percentaje because on the viewDidLoad it would be called once.

Comment: Of course, I tested my view in the playground and it's working as expected, so there must be something else in your code that is wrong

Comment: I put `var badge: BadgeView!` on the ViewController, did I declare it right?